# Pandas, TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply a function on a few columns in a pandas `df` but I keep on getting the following error.

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

This is the code I used:

```
unret = lambda v: float(re.sub("[^\d\.]", "", v))

object_list = ['GDP (Billions, PPP)','GDP per Capita (PPP)','FDI Inflow (Millions)']

df[object_list] = df[object_list].apply(unret)
```

To basically convert objects in the form '$xxx,xxx' (x is a number) to a float.

I tried converting the columns from object to string by applying `.astype(str)`, `.astype("string")`, `.astype("|S)`. I still keep on getting the error.

Comment: can you please post your df, or a sample thereof, as code, following these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @piterbarg, I found the soln

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply `re` to lists directly, you need to apply it item by item.

```py
unret = lambda v: float(re.sub("[^\d\.]", "", v))

object_list = ['GDP (Billions, PPP)','GDP per Capita (PPP)','FDI Inflow (Millions)']

df[object_list] = df[object_list].astype("string")

for v in object_list:
    df[v] = [unret(i) for i in df[v]]
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66505195/2) to the question [Pandas, TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66505195/pandas-typeerror-expected-string-or-bytes-like-object) by the OP [bboyenergetic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12678190/bboyenergetic) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>